# What can cause @Primary to not have its intended effect?

Tags: spring, autowired

In a Spring Boot app, I have the following:

```
public interface Car {
    ⋮
}

@Component
public class OldCar implements Car {
    ⋮
}

@Component
@Primary
public class NewCar implements Car {
    ⋮
}

@Component
public class Driver {

    @Autowired
    private Car theCar;

    ⋮

}
```

(Note: Names of classes have been changed to protect company secrets. :-)

When I launch this app, it bombs with a `NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException`, specifying:

> Could not autowire field ... theCar; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException No qualifying bean of type [Car] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: newCar,oldCar

However, if I modify the type of `theCar` to either `OldCar` or `NewCar` (to eliminate the ambiguity), everything works fine.

It seems to me that `@Primary` is not having its intended effect.  I am looking for ideas about what I can examine in order to discover potential causes of this unexpected behavior.

What could cause this?  Why is `@Primary` not working?